# Insertion sort doesn't work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I don't know why my script doesn't work it returns the same length as my input but the algorythm, seem to don't work.

```js
var n = prompt("Entrer la taille de votre tableau:");

a = new Array();
b = new Array();

a.length = n;
b.length = n;

var i = 0,
  j = 0;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

  a[i] = prompt("Entrer les valeurs de votre tableau:");

};


console.log(a);

// Algorithm part :

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  b[j] = a[i];
  for (j = i; j > 0 && a[j - 1] > b[i]; j--) {
    a[j] = a[j - 1];
  }
  a[j] = b[i];
}



console.log(b);
console.log(b.length);
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure how you envisioned that code working. You're using `i` in places where you should be using `j` and assigning values back and forth between arrays `a` and `b` in a way that doesn't make sense to me.

The way to make this work is to only work within the `b` array, and just copy values in from `a` one at a time. In the inner loop, `j` should be initialized to the value of `i`, but `i` shouldn't be used in that loop after that.

One more problem was that you weren't converting the inputs to numbers, so all of the comparisons were being made as string comparisons.

The following should work:

```js
var n = prompt("Entrer la taille de votre tableau:");

a = new Array();
b = new Array();

a.length = n;
b.length = n;

var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var temp;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

  a[i] = Number(prompt("Entrer les valeurs de votre tableau:"));

};


console.log(a);

// Algorithm part :

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  // Place the ith value of a in b
  b[i] = a[i];

  // Move backwards from i, swapping values until the inserted value is in the correct place
  for (j = i; j > 0 && b[j - 1] > b[j]; j--) {
    // swap
    temp = b[j];
    b[j] = b[j - 1];
    b[j - 1] = temp;        
  }
}

console.log(b);
console.log(b.length);
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: Just to say that what you are doing there, using a temp value, is not really an insertion sort, but more like one sweep of a bubble sort.  The point behind insertion (vs bubble) is the requirement for fewer swaps like that.  Of course insertion sort works best for a linked-list type of structure rather than an in-memory array so the difference is probably academic, however the temp value and the swap is not needed.

Comment: Yes i just wanted to make work any sort at the beginning it was insertion then it was bubble thanks for underline it !

Answer (score 0):

j is not defined at the start of the loop, so the line 'b[j]=a[i]' does not do what you might expect.  You are also sorting in `a` not in `b`.  I don't think that is what you intended so the following code sorts in b.

```
//define some values
const a=[3,6,8,4,5,2,7,1];
const n=a.length;
const b=new Array(n);

//now do the insertion sort
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  let j;
  for (j = i; j > 0 && b[j - 1] > a[i]; j--) {
    b[j] = b[j - 1];
  }
  b[j] = a[i];
}

console.log(b);
```